# VB.NET Admin and standard user login failure

Tags: vb.net

My Database :

```
username | password | user_ty

   roger | 54321    |  admin    

   maire | 12345    |  user
```

I can't login to different form.
It just displaying "Incorrect Username or Password." for both username.

```
Try
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.10.3;Initial Catalog=IT_INV;user id=sa;password=1n@r")
    con.Open()
    Dim rs As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE username=@username AND passw=@password", con)

    Dim usernameParam As New SqlParameter("@username", Me.TextBox1.Text)
    Dim passwordParam As New SqlParameter("@password", Me.TextBox2.Text)

    rs.Parameters.Add(usernameParam)
    rs.Parameters.Add(passwordParam)

    Dim sqlRead As SqlDataReader = rs.ExecuteReader
    If sqlRead.HasRows Then
        If sqlRead.Read = True Then
            If sqlRead("user_ty") = "admin" Then
                form2.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            ElseIf sqlRead("user_ty") = "user" Then
                form3.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                TextBox1.Text = ""
                TextBox2.Text = ""

            End If
        End If
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how to post code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this method:

```
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()
    Dim sSQL As String

    Try

        With cn
            .ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.10.3;Initial Catalog=IT_INV;user id=sa;password=1n@r"
            .Open()
        End With
        With rs
            .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
            .CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic
            .LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic
        End With

        sSQL = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE username='{0}' AND passw='{1}'", Me.TextBox1.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text)
        rs.Open(sSQL, cn)

        If Not rs.EOF Then

            Select Case rs.Fields("user_ty").Value.ToString
                Case "admin"
                    form2.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                Case "user"
                    form3.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                Case Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    TextBox2.Text = ""
            End Select

        End If

        rs.Close()
        cn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    rs = Nothing
    cn = Nothing
```